# Where are the auto-saved drafts stored?

Tags: support, draft

Is the content for an auto-saved draft located on the server, or on the client/browser side?

When I'm writing a answer or question I see a small-sized text display, *"draft saved"* under that textarea. If I don't submit that form, my content remains in that textarea. And I will see it even after several days.

Is that text stored in the database? Or just a localstorage?